# C2679 struct context

Tags: c++, set

Hi stack overflow I have a problem with set from stl, my problem is :

Input :

```
3
2,2,3
American Beauty#2002
Iron Man#2012
Interstellar#2014
Iron Man#2012
Inception#2010
Forrest Gump#1994
Iron Man#2012
```

SetTask2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Movie {
    string movieName;
    int movieYear;
};

bool operator<(const Movie& m1, Movie& m2);
void SetTask2();
```

SetTask2.cpp :

```
    #include "SetTask2.h"

bool operator<(const Movie& m1, Movie& m2) {
    return m1.movieYear <= m2.movieYear;
}

void SetTask2() {
    ifstream in("SetTask2.in");
    int numberOfPersons;
    in >> numberOfPersons;

    vector<set<Movie>> preferences;

    string prefNumberS;
    in >> prefNumberS;
    for (int i = 0; i < prefNumberS.size(); i++) {
        if (prefNumberS[i] != ',') {
            int number = (int)prefNumberS[i] - 48;

            string mName;
            string mYear;

            Movie m;
            set<Movie> s;

            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
            {
                getline(in, mName, '#');
                getline(in, mYear, '\n');
                m.movieName = mName;
                m.movieYear = stoi(mYear);

                s.insert(m);
                preferences.push_back(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "SetTask2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    SetTask2(); // Set : Task 2

    return 0;
}
```

Then I get this error:

Error   C2679   binary '<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Movie' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Can you tell me why?

Comment: Can you please post sufficient code for us to reproduce this issue? I suspect the error might be defining `operator <` after trying to use the `std::set`.

Comment: I edit the question with content of files now.

Answer (score 1):

> Error C2679 binary '<': no operator found which takes a **right-hand** operand of type 'const Movie' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Your `operator<` is only defined for a **left-hand** `const Movie&`, you need to modify it to make the **right-hand** operand `const`.

I note that using the numerical `<=` operator for your `<` override might introduce unintended behavior when sorting. If your intention is to sort movies by year then return `m1.year < m2.year`, not `m1.year <= m2.year`.

```
bool operator < (const Movie& left, const Movie& right) {

    return left.movieYear < right.movieYear;
}
```

Also, don't use `using namespace` in a header file. It causes scope pollution in consumers of your header file and may introduce naming collisions. If you look at the final `Main.cpp` translation unit you'll see you have the `using namespace std` statement twice.

Comment: Thank youu all are clear now !! Have a good day :D, I forgot the const for second parameter ...